# .NET 1.1 and MS SQL 2005 problem

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, web-applications, .net-1.1

Suddenly I'm getting the following error on all web applications using dotNET 1.1 and trying to access MS SQL 2005. The applications and SQL server run on the same machine.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Message: General network error.  Check your network documentation.
```

I have googled the following and tried all suggested solutions, but none of them worked.

The error appear for no particular reason, and now I'm stuck.

Comment: Agree with Sev, but can you post up the full exception details? Occassionally there can be other nuggets of info that don't appear in the Message.

Comment: There is no detailed exception message present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this has been working and has then stopped unexpectedly, the most likely reason for this problem is a hotfix that has been applied to your machine.

An easy thing to try to sort it out would be to use regiis to uninstall and re-install asp.net against IIS.

The utility is usually in: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322 (for .NET 1.1) and you run it command prompt like this...

```
aspnet_regiis \u
```

Then when that's done, just do...

```
aspnet_regiis \i
```

To re-install it against IIS.

Comment: Right now I'm reinstalling all dotNET frameworks on my machine, as the same was suggested on some forum. Will see if it works.

Comment: The reinstall of dotNET Framework 1.1 and un / registration of it against IIS provided the solution.